# Github - Limit the size of the Push

Tags: git, github

In my team our Product Manager wants to be notified when a developer does a large push as it is more likely to contain bugs. I was looking in the GitHub documentation and did not find anything useful, anyone has any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Look at git hooks

Comment: Yes i looked at it but when i looked at https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent most of the solutions were about counting the size of commits in that push and not exactly the size of the files per commit. Help is appreciated